# Set the screen brightness to the minimum

Tags: android, screen, brightness

I have problems trying to set the screen brightness to the minimum. My code is the following:

```
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = w.getAttributes();
        params.screenBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;
        w.setAttributes(params);
```

The problem is that the screen turns off completely in some devices and it is almost impossible to turn the screen on again even pressing the power button (fortunately the screen turns on again after a while). I have no idea about this behavior.

Help please. Thanks in advance.

Fran.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

And also check the Official Documentation
[Screen Brightness](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness)

try change the values with 0.1 precision in `layout.screenBrightness = 0.1F` or 0.2F and so on.

I hope this helps your needs.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. The value of WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF is 0 and it is what I need to set the brightness to the minimum. However, it works when the value is 0.1f but the screen is too bright.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it on zero

```
private fun Window.setScreenBrightness(brightness: Float) {
    val lp = attributes
    lp.screenBrightness = brightness
    attributes = lp
}

window.setScreenBrightness(0f)
```